# Get Longitude and Latitude from PostCode

Tags: c#, winforms, coordinates

I am developing a Winforms app in c#. What is the best way to turn a post code in to a set of co-ordinates so I can plot them on a map?

Thanks

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/22/10000406.aspx

Comment: Is your postcode limited to a particular country or not?  If not, you'll need to add the country to that postcode.  For the actual geo-locating you can use any of a number of geo-coding services available, including Google, Yahoo, Bing.  For example, have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545004.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your requirements are for a relatively small number of queries and you'll have a web connection, you can use Google Maps API to search for the postcode, and retrieve out the latitude and longitude.  However, it does rate-limit you.  See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ for more information on doing this with Google.  Bing Maps can also be used if you prefer.

-- updated following clarifying comment

For just UK, you may be able to use OS OpenData (http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-opendata.html) which provides Coordinates (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easting_and_northing) for every UK postcode in a downloadable CSV file.

Comment: To go from Eastings and Northings (OS coordinates) to Latitude/Longitude see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/vemapcontroldev/thread/2c5498bb-998b-4c05-a6af-36af9d051a3d

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[GeoCoding.NET](https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net)**, a generic .NET GeoCoding API.

With this, you can pass a post code string to a method and use one of Google, Bing or Yahoo's geolocation APIs to return a collection of potential matches: Each match may have latitude and longitude coordinates associated with it.

Bear in mind that there may be a limit on the number of requests that you can make to each particular service in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in the United States - the USPS has a whole slew of cool APIs that provide information about addresses.

https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm

But there are a lot of others.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Obtaining_geographic_coordinates